# Autofill Bug in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

What is going on here? In Chrome, if you click on an input, you get autocomplete for `country`. If you change `country` to `city`, you get autocomplete for `city`.

This is a minimal case. If you get rid of the table or get rid of an input, the behavior goes away.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input autocomplete="off">
            <input autocomplete="off">
            <input autocomplete="off">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am running Chrome, Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)
(I just upgraded to 89.0.4389.90, and the problem is still there.)

Try it: https://codepen.io/timkay/pen/abBMGRE

---

[image: chrome autofill bug]

Comment: I actually ran into this not too long ago and found that most browsers just simply refuse to adhere to the `autocomplete` attribute - see [this discussion](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8) for latest workarounds.

Comment: It's not an issue with autocomplete being disregarded. Somehow having the word "country" or "city" in a preceding table cell *and* three input fields causes this behavior. Change any of that, and the problem goes away.

Comment: Interesting, seems to exist for any geographical keyword that browsers look for in an address. The words "address", "county" also behave the same, and only when more than two inputs are within the table - though with the `autocomplete` attribute added I would expect browsers to not display autofill suggestions.

Comment: A workaround is to change the word `country`, so the browser doesn't recognize it, such as `<div>c<span style="display: none;">x</span>ountry</div>`. It's not enough to put other words in there. If the word `country` (or `city` or whatever) appears in the middle of a bunch of other words, the issue still exhibits.

Comment: Not a clean solution but if it prevents the browser from providing autocomplete suggestions, it'll have to do - you should post an answer to your question for others in the future, maybe someone will come along and find a cleaned workaround to this.

Comment: Thanks, @Skully, I posted an answer with the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I found an ugly workaround: change any troublesome words like `country`, `city`, `address`, etc., so that the browser doesn't recognize them. Here is an example:

```
<div><span style="display: none;">x</span>country</div>
```